# Получение класса из таблицы после запроса к БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, phpmyadmin, datatable

Всем привет.

Есть у меня база данных Mysql на phpmyadmin (запускаю её через xampp), в которой есть таблица со столбцами: Id (VarChar (36) - в нём хранится Guid пользователя), Username (TinyText - в нём хранится string с именем пользователя).

Так же, есть сервер, на котором реализовано получение всех пользователей:

```
public IReadOnlyList<IUser> GetUsers() =>
            ConnectionClass.GetTable($"SELECT * FROM users")
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(row =>
                new UserClass(
                    row.Field<Guid>("Id"),
                    row.Field<string>("Username"))).ToList();
```

(интерфейс IUser)

```
public interface IUser
{
    public Guid Id { get; }

    public string UserName { get; }
}
```

(класс, реализующий IUser)

```
internal class UserClass : IUser
{
    public Guid Id { get; }

    public string UserName { get; }

    public UserClass(Guid id, string username) =>
        (Id, UserName) = (id, username);
}
```

Добавлять пользователей в таблицу я могу, а вот получать - нет. При вызове метода GetUsers с клиента получаю исключение:
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1: "Заданное приведение является недопустимым.".

У меня есть очень большое предположение, что что-то не так с собственно самим методом GetUsers, но что именно - не могу сказать

Структура таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрос для создания таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `Id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `Username` tinytext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

UPD:
Нашёл способ реализации через Json, но выглядит это крайне некрасиво...

```
var q = ConnectionClass.GetTable($"SELECT * FROM users");
string serialize = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(q, Formatting.Indented);
List<UserClass> clslist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserClass>>(serialize, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
IReadOnlyList<IUser> users = clslist.ToList();
```

Comment: phpmyadmin - это веб интерфейс, а не база данных.

Comment: Ой, опечатался. База MySql. Поправил в тексте

Comment: Схему таблицы покажете? Или в Вангу играть опять?

Comment: Я ведь, вроде, описал её выше, ноооо ладно, в тексте прикрепил структуру её

Comment: `Guid.Parse(row.Field<string>("Id")),` пробовали?